# Shell Script Showing syntax error for dollar $

Tags: shell, unix, syntax-error

```
#!/bin/bash    

LIMIT='50'     
DIR="( $(df -Ph | column -t | awk '{print $5}' | grep -v Use) )"        
for i in $DIR;    
do    
    USED=$(df -Ph $i | awk '{print $5}' | sed -ne 2p | cut -d"%" -f1)    

    if [ "$USED" -gt "$LIMIT" ];    
       #If used space is bigger than LIMIT    
    then    
       #####    
    
    fi    
done
```

Why am I getting syntax error at line 5 ? in for loop for variable $DIR?

Comment: When I ran your script locally, I see __$DIR__ as __( Capacity 7% 100% 36% 3% 0Bi )__ so when you loop you will see __i__ as __(__ and __df -PH $i__ will not work. I do not see issue with line#5. Are you sure it is the same line in now formatted post?

Comment: If you are trying to construct an array from the output of the `df | grep` pipe, you need to drop the `"` and write `DIR=( $( df ... ) )`

Comment: The `column -t` is completely useless, and you can omit the `grep` by writing `$(df -Ph | awk '!/Use/{print $5}')`, but it seems like you really just want `$(df -Ph | awk 'NR>1{print $5}')`

Comment: But parsing `df` this way is pretty fragile.  The entry in the columns may contain whitespace (eg, the first column may be "map auto_home")

Comment: The loop doesn't do what you want it to do, but it doesn't look like a syntax error at a glance. Can you edit the question to show the specific error?

Comment: By the way, to have an assignment an array, the parenthesis need to be syntactic, not literal. And then you need to use `for item in "${array[@]}"` to loop over them. But even then, `array=( $(...) )`, though an actual array assignment, is not reliable code -- better to `readarray -t array <(...)` or use `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a array < <(... && printf '\0')` if you need compatibility with older bash releases or failed exit status to be passed through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the fundamental error is the quotes in the assignment of the array.  Instead of `DIR="( $(...) )"`, you need to drop the quotes and use `DIR=( $(...) )`.  However, that assignment isn't necessary at all!

You probably shouldn't parse `df` like this, but you definitely should not be running `df` multiple time.  There's no need for the embedded loop. Since you haven't really should what you're doing in the cases when the filesystem use is over the limit, it's hard to give better code, but whatever you're doing there can almost certainly be done easily in awk.  Or, if not in awk, you can use `awk` rather than the embedded loop to trigger the action.  eg, you could just do:

```
df -Ph | awk 'NR>1{printf("%s: %s than limit\n", $1, $5 + 0> limit ? "bigger" : "smaller")}' limit="${LIMIT-50}"
```

altough it probably makes more sense to do:

```
df -Ph | awk 'NR>1 && $5 + 0 > limit {print $1 " is over limit" > "/dev/stderr"}' limit="${LIMIT-50}"
```

note that both of these fail horribly if any of the column of the output of `df` contain whitespace (eg "map auto_home").  The output of `df` is intended for human consumption, and is not really suited to this sort of thing.  You could do a column count in the awk (or use `$(NF-1)` instead of `$5`) and get the Capacity that way, but that's just moving the fragility.

Comment: Thank u William , I think without finding bug in my code,I should go with your code solution. What to do if I want to change the PRINT to some other action like -send SMS ?
I have SMS sending code , please point out the block where I can add the SMS sending.